# Show the improper integral $\int^{\infty}_0 \frac 1 y e^{-y} dy$ doesn't converge.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> Show the improper integral $\int^{\infty}_0 \frac 1 y e^{-y} dy$ doesn't converge.

Using Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8ab70731b1553f17c11a3bbc87e0b605 the result is as stated (divergent)

I know I can prove that $$\int^{\infty}_0 \frac 1 y e^{-y} dy$$ doesn't converge if I can find a divergent function $f(y): 0 \le f(y) \le \frac 1 y e^{-y}$ for $y \rightarrow \infty$.

Can someone come up with such a function ? I was thinking $f(y) = \frac 1 y$ because I know the series corresponding to $\{\frac 1 n\}$ is divergent, but this function doesn't have the desired property.

Comment: The problem with divergence lies in the point $0$, not in $\infty$.

Comment: @user111854  i think it diverges because it blows up near zero so just consider the definite integral for 0 to 1 and limit it by using 1/y

Comment: Near $0$ the integrand behaves as $1/y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y>1$, the value $\frac{1}{y}e^{-y}$ is smaller than $e^{-y}$, and since the integral $\int_1^\infty e^{-y}dy$ converges, the integral $$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{y}e^{-y}dy$$ also converges. That should tell you that the problem with the integral may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Ahh ... But what function can I use to show the integral of $\frac 1 y e^{-y}$ on $(0,1]$ is arbirarily large ?

Comment: My hint would be this: on $(0,1]$, the function $e^{-y}$ takes only values in $[1,e]$.

Comment: I see, so we can use $\frac e y \ge \frac 1 y e^{-y}$ and $\frac e y \rightarrow \infty$ for $y \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yes, but that does not yet prove that the integral does not exist. For example, the integral $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt y}dy$$ exists.

Comment: But $\int \frac e y \ dy = e \ln(y)$ and $e \ln(y) ]^1_{0_+} = 0 - (\lim_{y \rightarrow 0_+} e \ln(y)) = \infty$ ? Is that enough ?

Comment: Indeed it is. You have proven that your function is smaller than a function which has no integral on $[0,1]$, thus proving the same for your function.

Comment: On $(0,1]$ the function $e^{-y}$ takes values in $[\frac 1 e,1)$ not $[1,e]$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But still, the point remains that it is bounded.